# Adjust Fixed width option in Text to Columns without a mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to apply "Text to Columns" without a mouse (we can use only keyboard)?
If yes, then how can we CREATE/DELETE/MOVE a break line for Fixed width Original data type?

Answer (score 1):

Any Microsoft program, including Excel, can be navigated with just the keyboard.  Start with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then follow the highlighted letters on the Ribbon.  For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>(Data),<kbd>E</kbd>(Text to Columns) will open the Text to Columns Wizard.  Then the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> will move you to the Fixed Width option.  You'll need @pnuts answer to address that option, there is no keyboard work-around for setting the widths manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround by ensuring Row1 has the spacing desired, something like say `XXXXX...  XX...XXX...XXX` (here the dots represent spaces) should serve as the template for skipping Step 2 of 3. Hopefully there IS a better answer, but it is not a question I have ever had to address, so sorry no key combination for this from me.